# USB Hard Drives being only Read-Only?

Tags: hard-drive, format, read-only

I have finally gotten my Hard drive to be formatted in FAT32 but now, when ever I try to move a file onto it, it says: "The destination is read-only." I have been looking through it in GParted and nothing seems to work. Any ideas?
Thanks to anybody that can help :)

Comment: Any reason you use fat32? I use NTFS with no issues

Answer (score 0):

you may try with ntfs-config. it might work for you. [read this](http://techgossipz.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-solve-this-destination-is-read.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.